# Spark simple select job very slow

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple job that selects all entries from a table. This job takes ~ 40sec. to complete.
Same query ( select * from users ) on the cassandra database returns all results immediately.
In the table there are ~ 180 entries. 
Spark master has ~ 64 GB ram and 10 cores.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
            .setMaster("spark://172.16.0.179:7077")
            .setJars(new String[] { "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.0.jar" })
            .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dhttp.proxyHost=172.16.0.179 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=172.16.0.179 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 ")
            .setAppName("test")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "172.16.0.179")
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "64g")
            .set("spark.driver.memory", "6g")

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spark);

    HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("keyspace", "testkeyspace");
    options.put("table", "users");
    sqlContext.read()
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(options)
            .load()
            .show(10);

    spark.stop();
}
```

Comment: Have you attached a debugger to determine which step(s) is/are slow?

Comment: I have put a timer around  ... sqlContext.read() .. this is the part that is consuming most of the time.

Comment: The entire line, or just that one method call? Consider breaking that up into separate statements and timing each call.

Comment: You should consider exploring the query using web UI. It'd be very helpful to have some screenshots included in your question.

Comment: What's the version of Spark? How do you `spark-submit` it?

Comment: Spark version is 2.4.0. I launch the above application from my local machine, I was assuming that this will be executed on the Spark cluster as I define the master-ip is this wrong?